# Find string in REQUEST_URI

Tags: php

I need help with searching the content of the `REQUEST_URI`.

If `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains `rmb_twi` then do something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is beyond simple. Read the manual entry for [strpos()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
if (false !== strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'rmb_twi')) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Answered the question, you did :)

Comment: @alex +1 On the [Yoda conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2430307#2430307) pickup.

Comment: Brown I was hoping someone would get the reference :)

Comment: @alex As was I (besides the fact that I always write conditionals this way)

Answer (score 3):

```
if (strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'rmb_twi')) {
   ...
}
```